# Best angularjs practices concerning dependent variables

Tags: angularjs, dependencies

I wonder what's the best practice for a simple page containing a couple of radio buttons and checkboxes and other stuff controlling the visibility of page sections.

I started with something like

```
<div ng-if="radio1==3 || !button2" ....>
```

and immediately started to hate it. [This page](http://thenittygritty.co/angularjs-pitfalls-using-scopes) advocates against using functions in the view and actually I'll need the expression later again, so I should probably use something like

```
<div ng-if="visible1" ....>
```

and update `visible1` accordingly. I tried

```
watch("radio1", function() {
    $scope.visible1 = $scope.radio1 == 3 && !button2;
})
```

but it didn't work, probably because of the variables being scalars. **Am I right?**

---

I replaced `$scope.radio` by `$scope.my_wonderful_model_aggregate.radio` and it worked, but it was a bit too much to type.

---

Adding `ng-click="updateVisible1();"` to all the buttons works, too, but then I could use jQuery instead. I guess it's the most efficient solution, but speed isn't important here. And it's prone to forgetting and feels non-declarative and pretty redundant.

---

In my case, writing a single function which updates all the "visible*" variables based on other scope variables is easy and feels good. The function is idempotent, so it's OK when it gets called multiple times, but **how can I ensure that it gets called only when needed?**

**Is there a better solution?** I'm looking for best practices.

Comment: use objects as much as possible. Inside scope can always set a variable to reference the `$scope.my_wonderful_model_aggregate` to cut down need to write out the whole thing for each use. `var data=$scope.my_wonderful_model_aggregate`